# Rails Truncate Method: Ignore html in a string in Length Count

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, truncate

I use a truncate method to truncate a string in my site. I truncate with the code:

```
 truncate(auto_link(textilize(post.content)), :length  => 140)
```

This truncation truncates the post content, but there is a problem with the content contains links. EG the post content is:

```
 <p>Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo 
 <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo 
 Yahoo </a> Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google  <a 
 href="http://www.google.com"> Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google 
 </a><br></p>
```

In this case, the all the html tags and the links get counted in the character count by truncate method, rather than the truncate method counting the characters that a viewer would actually see:

```
 Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo
 Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo Yahoo  (etc..)
```

Is there any work around here for the truncation method?

EDIT: new example to clear up ambiguities:

Users post their posts in plain text, and are allow to use textile for some formatting. In terms of posting links, I allow users to (a) paste plain urls (http://www.site.com, www.site.com, etc..), (b) use textile syntax which converts "the click me text":http://www.example.com to [the click me text](http://www.example.com) or  take their time to embed links in html form.

I want a page that has snippets of a person's posts to show only the first, say, 140 characters of their post. But I want this to be 140 characters of the text that a reader would see. In other words, let's say a user's post starts as:

```
 Today I went to the market to pick up some fruit. "At the market there was this awesome
 fruit display!":http://www.externalsite.com/picture.jpg Definitely want to go back 
 tomorrow!
```

This will be converted by textilize to a string of 193 characters:

```
 Today I went to the market to pick up some fruit. <a href="http://www.externalsite.com/picture.jpg"> 
 At the market there was this awesome fruit display!</a> Definitely want to go back 
 tomorrow!
```

The text the user will see on a page is only 138 characters:

```
 Today I went to the market to pick up some fruit. At the market there was this awesome
 fruit display! Definitely want to go back tomorrow!
```

The 193 character long text would be truncated by truncate, but if I had a work around the whole text would display, ending up appearing as just 138 characters with the link embedded.

Comment: well, i guess that I could remove links for a snippet, -- that may be wise in the long run. But I'm now also interested in learning how to work around this problem. And I'm adding auto_link because I allow users to paste in links (eg typing "www.google.com" in plain text") and would like this to become a clickable link for the time being. I'm adding some edits to be more specific in this question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, to get an accurate count without links, one can do:

```
 count = strip_tags(string).count
```

(This is for a string that has html tags in it. If the string needs to be 'textilized' etc.. first, then the code is count = strip_tags(textilize(string)).count).

Rather than use truncate, I just limited the count to 140 characters of this true count ie switched this to a validation on the field.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a string with all the links in it. So truncate does it right. What you need is to pass things through a method which only gives you back the text that is linked (which should be truncated, I guess).

You could use a RegEx for this to get the linked string, e.g. (not tested)

```
post.content.gsub /<a[\w\"]*>([a-z]*)<\/a>/i do |link_text|
  truncate(auto_link(link_text), :truncate => 40)
end
```

Comment: `post.content` is plain text, `auto_link` is producing the links. Your regex is pointless and you'll still be producing invalid HTML.

Comment: @mu is too short thanks for your nice words, this always encourages me to try and help. I don't exactly know what he is doing, I just assumed he needs to extract the link string from his links to truncate them and provided a *not tested example*. No need to get cocky.

Comment: Maybe that was poorly worded, my apologies if I came of a bit gruff; nice diplomatic response though. The question is rather confusing at the moment though, applying `auto_link` to HTML doesn't make much sense. I'm reading it as "`post.content` is plain text that is being auto-linked and then truncated", the same post doesn't match what he's doing with it.

Comment: @pduerseteler, basically on one page, i'm trying to show a snippet of a post's content. I allow a user to use textile or html to embed links. Therefore, if a link is embedded, I don't want the html to count toward the character count, otherwise the resulting truncated post will appear shorter than I'd like -- I'll add an edit to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to truncate a text containing HTML code.

I suggest you to use plain text. Otherwise, an alternative would be

1. use `auto_link`
2. replace every link with a 1 char placeholder, example $
3. truncate
4. replace back every placeholder with the old corresponding link

It's a kind of a hack, but it should work. Again, I suggest you to use plain text when you truncate.

Comment: posted an example. The user's post starts as plain text. But I would like for them to be able to post links as well. Should these links be embedded, I don't want them to be counted. Yeah  see that your hack could potentially work. Still trying to figure out if there are other options. Thanks!